# Why did the stormtrooper flinch from sand?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, stormtroopers

In the Rogue One film, during the fight scene between Chirrut Îmwe and the stormtroopers at Jedha, Chirrut kicks up some sand towards a stormtrooper, the stormtrooper flinches and as a result gets knocked down a moment later.

[image]

Why did this stormtrooper flinch from a tiny bit of sand/dust while he was wearing his helmet? Was he scared and was this his reaction to possibly being hit with something?

Comment: I should imagine that it was purely instinctive.

Comment: So that he'd be distinct enough to have a special action figure made for him.

Comment: This whole ridiculous combat scene didn't work for me. I found myself sympathizing with the stormtroopers, who were incredibly getting beat up by a blind guy with a staff.

Comment: Because it's coarse and it gets everywhere?

Comment: See the title text of https://www.xkcd.com/1670/ "Laws of Physics"

Comment: @RobertF - A Force-using blind guy with a staff made of  wood that was harder than their armor.

Comment: @Adamant Right, I understand the creators of Rogue One wanted a Wuxia-style martial arts character in Star Wars. But why didn't the stormtroopers just shoot him with their blasters & be done with it?

Comment: @RobertF - I believe they did try. Didn’t they end up shooting each other? The Force is a useful thing.... Not to mention that they were caught by surprise.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I dare say that it was just pure and utter defensive instinct. You can observe it time and again also in real life. Whenever something comes at you with high velocity your instincts and reflexes kick in when you become aware of it. And if you are not trained otherwise the first reflex is to protect yourself, which is just what the stormtrooper tries there...despite having a helmet. So it is a purely human reaction there.

On another note...a combat droid would have fared better there (example B1s) as they usually don't have that self preservation instinct that leads to one trying to shield oneself from harm and damage.

Comment: I've ducked from a butterfly that "suddenly" entered my peripheral vision 10+ yards away before.

Comment: Partially related note: I almost crashed my car once because a bird flew straight at the windscreen and tucked up just in time to go over the roof. Whereas I flinched, covered my face and ducked below the steering wheel!

Comment: @TheLethalCoder yepp good reflexes can be something good (if the bird had flown straight and no windshield there) and something hampering like in your case where they almost caused an accident.

Comment: It's almost like this military force has zero training of any kind